# What is the meaning of this code?

Tags: c, enums

Please help me understand the meaning of this code. I have seen this kind of usage for the first time

```
typedef enum {

        E_1_DEFAULT = 0,
        E_1_1,
        E_1_2,
        E_1_3,
        E_1_4,
        E_1_5,
        E_1_255 = 255           //needs at least 8Bit

} APPLICATION_ENUM_1;                           

typedef enum {

        E_2_DEFAULT = 0,
        E_2_1,
        E_2_2,
        E_2_3                   //needs at least 2Bit

} APPLICATION_ENUM_2;                           

typedef enum {

        E_3_DEFAULT = 0,
        E_3_1,
        E_3_2,
        E_3_3,
        E_3_4,
        E_3_5,
        E_3_666 = 666           //needs at least 10Bit

} APPLICATION_ENUM_3;



typedef struct {

        APPLICATION_ENUM_3      var3:10;                // 10Bit
        APPLICATION_ENUM_1      var1:8;         // 18Bit
        APPLICATION_ENUM_2      var2:2;         // 20Bit
        uint8                   unnused_1:4;   // fill up the last whole byte -> 24Bit = 3byte

} APPLICATION_RAM;;
```

Comment: You might want to get yourself a decent introductory book on C, C++ or whatever related language this is, and start at chapter one.

Comment: @Jesper: what makes you think this is necessarily C++ ? It looks more like C, but it could equally well be something else, e.g. Objective-C.

Comment: @PaulR I am yet to find a C / C++ book that covers bitfields in chapter  1 if at all

Comment: @Jesper I'd argue that the use of `typedef` of an anonymous struct marks it as C, not C++.  @bubble -- can you tag this with whatever language you are asking about?

Comment: @parapura: perhaps, but if enums are unfamiliar then that suggests that it's time to read a good introductory book before going much further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C++ standard

> The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration.

Now lets look at the first definition

```
typedef enum {

        E_1_DEFAULT = 0,
        E_1_1,
        E_1_2,
        E_1_3,
        E_1_4,
        E_1_5,
        E_1_255 = 255           //needs at least 8Bit

} APPLICATION_ENUM_1;
```

definition `E_1_255 = 255` ensures that all values from `0 to 255` can be represented by this enum type  and you need at least 8bits to represent all values from `0 to 255`

```
typedef struct {

        APPLICATION_ENUM_3      var3:10;                // 10Bit
        APPLICATION_ENUM_1      var1:8;         // 18Bit
        APPLICATION_ENUM_2      var2:2;         // 20Bit
        uint8                   unnused_1:4;   // 24Bit = 3byte

} APPLICATION_RAM;
```

The above struct is using a seldom used [bitfield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) construct. Basically declaring the `APPLICATION_RAM` as a struct that has a

- `var3` member that is 10 bits
- `var1` member that is 8 bits
- `var2` member that is 2 bits
- `unnused_1` member that is 4 bits